# Sul significato in uso del verbo implementare

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Tempo fa pensavo di sapere cosa significasse il verbo "implementare", che ho sempre usato nel senso di "realizzare praticamente qualcosa che prima era stato specificato solo a livello di progetto".

Sempre più spesso però vedo che questo verbo viene impiegato con un altro significato, per me piuttosto diverso, ovvero "migliorare" o "rendere più performante qualcosa", come nella frase:

> Il sistema è stato implementato con un aumento della memoria,

dove non si intende che il sistema è stato realizzato con più memoria rispetto a quanto previsto nel progetto, ma semplicemente che si è aggiunta memoria ad un sistema già esistente.

Su alcuni dizionari ho trovato entrambi i significati, addirittura [qui](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=implementare) ho trovato indicato prima il significato che io ritenevo errato.

Dato che in molti casi i due significati contrastanti potrebbero trarre in inganno, vorrei sapere qual è il vero significato del verbo.

Comment: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implementazione in pratica risponde alla tua domanda.

Comment: "Il sistema è stato aggiornato implementando un aumento della memoria"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nei dizionari di cui personalmente mi fido di più, il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/implementare/) e lo Zingarelli, è presente solo il significato di base che dici: «dare pratica realizzazione a un piano» e sue sfumature, coerentemente con l'etimo. Il verbo, anche con questo significato, è un calco dall'inglese molto recente (lo Zingarelli lo fa risalire al 1983); ritengo che l'altro significato sia ancor più recente e forse originato da un uso erroneo.

D'altro canto, è innegabile che venga usato anche nell'altro senso: quale dei due sensi sia prevalente quantitativamente si potrebbe sapere solo esaminando un corpus di testi.

Personalmente, spero che non si diffonda più di tanto il secondo senso, proprio per evitare i malintesi a cui accenni.

Comment: Anch'io conoscevo solo il primo significato, e la frase la intendo come "realizzato con un aumento della memoria" (rispetto allo stesso sistema realizzato precedentemente)... sarei curioso di sapere come gli si è attaccato il secondo significato, cosa è: una sbagliata traduzione di incrementato?

Comment: Sì, @ErikvanDoren, penso che c'entrino varie assonanze: appunto con “incrementare”, nonché con “integrare”, “completare”, “aumentare”.

Comment: Concordo decisamente con l'ultima frase della tua risposta – anzi, eliminerei il “più di tanto”.

Comment: La voce [Implementazione su Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implementazione) dice correttamente che «il verbo "implementare" è spesso oggetto di [paronimia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paronimia), quando viene usato, in maniera erronea, con il significato di "incrementare", "aggiungere", "aggiungere caratteristiche/funzionalità", "aggiungere parti o pezzi"»